# What is this a mistranlation of?

Tags: translation, expressions

I ran across this pillow

[image: You are in my heart. Lonely but afraid.]

the other day and thought that the expression was a little odd. [According to this one girl on Instagram](http://www.pictaram.com/media/1306372356112918073_910069957) (a very reliable source, I know) it's a #mistranslation. This, along with the fact that if you Google the exact phrase there are a couple of Chinese web pages leads me to believe that "You are in my heart. Lonely but afraid." is a mistranslated Chinese expression. What is the correct and/or untranslated expression?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chinese idiom 心如鹿撞 that has " deer" and " heart" in the same phrase. It means "like a deer is ramming the heart"

We use this phrase to describe someone's heart is pounding due to excitement or fear.

For example:

1. When you are alone with someone you love in the dark. The anticipation and excitement would make your heart pounds (心如鹿撞)
2. When you are stopped in traffic by a police officer, with a dead body in your car trunk. You may try to act calm, but the anxiety and fear would make your heart pump like crazy(心如鹿撞)

As for the deer image and the phrase "you are in my heart" (implies a headline: "a deer is in my heart")--  It  should be followed by the subline: " **My heart is pounding in excitement**" instead of " *lonely but afraid*" (you don't have a dead body under your bed, do you?)

Comment: Who came up with the idea of "heart pounding" is a good message on a pillow?

Comment: Don't know, but you can buy one on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01D2R82AW). Also there are no bodies under my bed ... I think.